# Update order meta after payment completion from orders page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment, hook-woocommerce

I want to update order meta after the payment completion from orders page.
I have used the hook 'woocommerce_payment_successful_result' but this hook fires only after payment is made from the cart. The hook should run after successful payment only.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_successful_result', 'my_function', 10, 2);
public function my_function( $result, $order_id ) {
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'payments', 'example data');
}
```

Comment: Not sure I get it, but did you try the `woocommerce_thankyou` hook?

Comment: I tried this hook but this hook also runs if the payment is not successful.

Comment: So as you are outside woocommerce normal process (not through checkout), with something very custom. Your question don't reflect this customizations and nobody can help you if you don't tell all related in details and if you don't add in your question all related code of your customizations (like custom paypal args)…

Comment: Hey LoicTheAztec Thanks. Basically I want the customers to pay second time from the orders page. I have implemented the functionality to pay only 10% deposit. After that I want them to pay 90% remaining amount from orders page. I have managed to sendthe 90% amount to paypal when clicked the pay button on orders page. Now when payment completes I want to store some order meta.